# Duplicate barcode in the same report

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I want to print in the same report page a determinate number of the same barcode, I used this code but it does not work:

```
' ###### I try to repeat the function to generate the same barcode 6 times #######
Private Sub ExampleBarcode_BeforePrint(sender As Object, e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs) Handles Me.BeforePrint
    For i As Integer = 1 To 6
        Me.Detail.Controls.Add(CreateQRCodeBarCode("01234ft78"))
    Next
End Sub

Public Function CreateQRCodeBarCode(ByVal BarCodeText As String) As XRBarCode

    Dim barCode As New XRBarCode()

    barCode.Symbology = New Code128Generator()

    barCode.Text = BarCodeText
    barCode.Width = 240
    barCode.Height = 70

    barCode.Module = 1

    CType(barCode.Symbology, Code128Generator).CalcCheckSum = False
    CType(barCode.Symbology, Code128Generator).CharacterSet = Code128Charset.CharsetAuto
    Return barCode
End Function
```

Comment: what is not working? Is XRbarCode a class that can be added to the contol-collection?

Comment: Is working but It print the barcode only one time, not 6 times in a row.                The problem is that I can´t upload an image to show what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your barcodes are located at the same location. You need to set different locations for each of the controls. For this you can use `LeftF` and `TopF` properties.
Here is example:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 5
    Dim barCode = CreateQRCodeBarCode("01234ft78")
    barCode.TopF = i * barCode.HeightF

    Me.Detail.Controls.Add(barCode)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it was what I needed